# Powershell continue script on Exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am a powershell newbie. I wrote this little script to find the DNS entries of my server list. When I run with several computernames, It is working fine without any issues. When it handles an invalid hostname, it is being caught by the catch block but the script just terminates instead of continuing with the next hostname. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function Resolve-Hostname
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    # One or more compternames
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               Position=0)]
    [string[]]$Computername
)

Begin
{
    $dns = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DNSHostname -ne $null} |  Select-Object DNS
    Write-verbose "DNS suffix order used -"
    $DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder = $dns | Select-Object DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
    Write-Verbose ( $DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder | ft -AutoSize | Out-String )
    Write-Verbose "DNS Servers order used -"
    $DNSServerSearchOrder = $dns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
    Write-Verbose ($DNSServerSearchOrder | Out-String )
}
Process
{
    try 
    {
        foreach ($computer in $Computername)
        {
            $dnsreport = [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve("$computer") 
            $dns = [pscustomobject]@{
                Hostname    = $computer
                DNS_Suffix  = $dnsreport.HostName.Split('.',2)[1]
                DNSHostname = $dnsreport.HostName
                IPAddress   = $dnsreport.AddressList.ipaddresstostring -join ", "
                Alias       = $dnsreport.Aliases
            }
            $dns
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        $dns = [pscustomobject]@{
                Hostname    = $computer
                DNS_Suffix  = '-'
                DNSHostname = '-'
                IPAddress   = '-'
                Alias       = '-'
        }
        $dns
    }
}
End
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `foreach` is inside the `try` block, so when an exception occurs, it goes to the `catch` block which is outside the loop. Put both the `try` and the `catch` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Silly me. I should learn to think simple. Thank you Briantist :)